# Weird C# SocketException

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception, xna

While testing my Client-Server program, I encountered a weird exception when trying to connect to the server on a different router:

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

The client can connect to the server perfectly in the local network, however it doesn't work when it is over the internet.

I port forwarded port 1250 (the one I'm using), and using SimplePortForwarding (http://www.simpleportforwarding.com/) I verified that the port was open and working.

I based my implementation on this tutorial:
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/

Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks!

Here is the server listen method:

```
    public void startListening(int port)
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            _listeningSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                // Bind socket to local endpoint, and listen for incoming connections
                IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                _listeningSocket.Bind(ipEndpoint);
                _listeningSocket.Listen(10);

                waitForNewClient();

                // successfully started listening
                _isListening = true;

            } catch (SocketException e)
            {
                // failed for some strange reason
                _isListening = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the client connect code:

```
    public String connect(String ipAddress, int port)
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            if (!_connecting)
            {
                _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);

                try
                {
                    _socket.Connect(endpoint);
                    _connected = true;
                    waitForData();

                    _eventManager.queueEvent(new PlayerJoinedEvent(PlayerJoinedEvent.PLAYER_JOINED, name));
                } catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    // Exception is thrown HERE
                    return e.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI, your weird exception is commonly known as a connection timeout.

Comment: Sorry, Yesterday was the first time I'd ever done any socket programming.

Comment: What IPAddress are you putting in connect?  IP addresses for a local LAN are typically different from Internet IP addresses.  If you use the same IP address for both LAN and Internet, then only one of them will work, based on the type of IP address you set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it sure that your Server IP address is [public](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Public_addresses) unless it is not reachable.

Check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) for private address spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You opened port 1250 on the server or the client router? It needs to be opened on the server router. You may need to make sure your server is connected to your DMZ port and/or have DMZ enabled on your server router.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the problem.

The IP Address I used was the internal ip address I got from ipconfig, but the IP address I needed to use was the external one, the one you get from services like http://www.whatsmyip.org/.

I'm still confused as to why these two numbers are different.

Comment: That is exactly what my answer is talking about. ;) You were using a private address assigned by your router and it is not reachable unless clients are in the same network. (i.e. under the same router). See this link for more details. http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-difference-between-public-and-private-ip-addresses.htm